# Testing CommonJS with dynamic imports of ESM with ts-jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, commonjs

Given a library that uses CommonJS module system, but imports ESM (only) modules with a dynamic import (to prevent TS from replacing `import` with `require`):

```
export async function loadEsmModule<T>(modulePath: string|URL): Promise<T> {
    const namespaceObject =
        (await new Function('modulePath', `return import(modulePath);`)(modulePath));

    // If it is not ESM then the values needed will be stored in the `default` property.
    if (namespaceObject.default) {
        return namespaceObject.default;
    } else {
        return namespaceObject;
    }
}
```

**What is a working configuration to run unit tests with `ts-jest` using CommonJS?**

What I tried in varying combinations (and failed):

1. Nodejs option `--experimental-vm-modules`: 
   Error: "A jest worker process (pid=2701) was terminated by another process: signal=SIGSEGV, exitCode=null. Operating system logs may contain more information on why this occurred."
2. Jest option `--runInBand`
   Error:  "Test environment has been torn down"
3. Setting jest options `maxWorkers` and `maxConcurrency` to large values.
4. Alternative [jest presets](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/presets/)

Other references:

- https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/11438

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, however I ran into the same issue on Node 18. Switching to Node 20 (lts/iron) seemed to work, so possibly some bug in Node 18?